# Base10 to Base64 in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently trying to get Decimal/Base10 - Base64, however, this is what I get:

```
current = data['user']['media']['nodes'][0]['id'] # This is the last media_id like 1448738878879486182

encoded = base64.b64encode(bytes(str(current), encoding='ascii'))
```

which returns `b'MTQ0ODczODg3MzM3OTQ4NjE5MQ=='`

However I need the base 64 math base conversion system. Any way to do so?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you want the result to look like?

Comment: Should look like this: BQa9FRgFXnv @glibdud

Comment: Can you add more detail? The relationship between the input and output is not clear,and the padding is incorrect.